# Logitech Webcam HD C270 not properly recognized by macOS

Tags: usb, microphone, webcam

I purchased a C270 (in early February) that I use with my Mac. However in Zoom and other software it identifies as **USB-camera #3** and the microphone identifies as **Unknown USB Audio Device**. When I plugged it into a Windows 10-laptop it was immediately identified as HD C270. I tried searching on the Logitech website for a new driver or anything but there isn't anything like that.

I find it a little annoying, especially since I also have a cheap USB microphone that identifies as `USB MICROPHONE`, I find it annoying that I can not see the proper labels in selection dialogs.

This is how the device shows up in `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`:

```
                Miscellaneous Device:

                  Product ID: 0x0825
                  Vendor ID: 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.)
                  Version: 0.12
                  Serial Number: A2CC4DD0
                  Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
                  Location ID: 0x14132100 / 20
                  Current Available (mA): 500
                  Current Required (mA): 500
                  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Is there any way I can add my own labels to this device?

Comment: Does the camera work as expected (so it's just the labels which are wrong)? Did you check on logi.com whether there are is any support software available?

Comment: My previous experience refuses to accept that out of all brands Logitech dropped the ball so badly. I bought C310 (nearly identical to C270), but it's also identified as "unknown usb audio device". There is a Camera Settings App, but it doesn't allow to change the device name.

Answer (score 3):

Many Logitech webcams have only the bare minimum support on Mac. From their descriptions…

> SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS
>   Compatible with:
>   Windows® 10 or later, Windows 8, Windows 7
>
> Works in USB Video Device Class (UVC) mode with supported video-calling clients:
>    macOS 10.10 or later

The only way I've ever been able to leverage any better behaviour from mine was to get [WebCam Settings](http://mactaris.blogspot.com) available from the App Store at $8. There's no free trial, so you'd have to take a punt, but the C270 is listed as supported.

From comments - apparently Logitech do now make software for Mac support.
The C270 can use the [Camera Settings](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360024692954--Downloads-HD-Webcam-C270) app.
My older C920 has a beta [Logitech Capture](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360024849133--Downloads-HD-Pro-Webcam-C920)

You are probably best going through from the front page for your own camera if it's not one of these, to see what's specifically on offer.

Comment: There is a settings app available on logi.com, not sure whether it helps though.

Comment: Ah… interesting. That didn't exist when I got mine. The C270 has the 'Camera Settings' app, my C920 has just a beta 'Logitech Capture' so I can't try their settings app.

Comment: Yeah, I have the settings app, that allows me to change white balance and so on, but does not help with improved device naming or such.

Comment: hmm… OK. I don't know for certain whether Webcam Settings will lever considerably more information or usage out of the camera than Logitech's own software. It *might* be worth a punt for 8 bucks, but you'd have to make that call - unless we can find someone reading this who already has the same cam & software pairing.